# Get Image's Actual Height and Width File Size in Disk

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I have an image tag:

HTML code:

```
<img src="image.jpg"></img>
```

CSS code:

```
img
{  
   max-width: 100%;
   max-height: 100%; 
}
```

I just want to know it's actual height and width in pixels(size in memory), if it's width and height is set to auto. How to do that in javascript?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/623172/how-to-get-image-size-height-width-using-javascript

Comment: @Marcin Lojewski -->Doesn't work with me, I want to know the image actual file size in Disk.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be doing it like this. This way you get the current height and width of the DOM-element.

```
<img id="someId" src="image.jpg"></img>

var imageElement = document.getElementById('someId'); 
var height = imageElement.clientHeight;
var width = imageElement.clientWidth;
```

Comment: Doesn't work with me, I want to know the image actual file size in Disk.

Answer (score 0):

clientWidth and clientHeight are DOM properties that show the current in-browser size of the inner dimensions of a DOM element (excluding margin and border). So in the case of an `img` element, this will get the actual dimensions of the visible image.

```
var img = document.getElementById('imageid');
 //or however you get a handle to the IMG
 var width = img.clientWidth;
 var height = img.clientHeight;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript to gather the element

Use for height
`document.querySelector('img').offsetHeight;`

Use for width
`document.querySelector('img').offsetWidth;`

Usually people set an `id` or a `class` on the element in order to easily grab it.

like this
`<img class='image' src='image.jpg'></img>`

now you can grab the element by its classname

`document.querySelector('.image').offsetHeight;`

Comment: Doesn't work with me, I want to know the image actual file size in Disk.